# Existence of a kind of balanced tournament schedule

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request

Recently I was confronted with another tournament design problem:

Suppose we have a tournament with $2n$ teams ($n\in \mathbb{N}$). We have $n$ different types of games (say at $n$ distinct locations), to be played by a pair of teams at a time. The tournament will be played in $2n$ rounds. In the first $n$ rounds as well as in the final $n$ rounds, each team should have played at every location. Each team should have confronted each of the other $2n-1$ teams in contest.

For which $n$ can this problem be solved and with what method? Relevant references / terminology?

I tried to solve it for $n=6$ (for practical application) and nearly succeeded. I got stuck with an arrangement where the final constraint is not completely satisfied.

Comment: I don't understand. To play in every location, a team must play $2n$ games, but it only plays $2n-1$.

Comment: @user58697 There are only $n$ locations.

Comment: @MikeEarnest The team shall play at every location in the first $n$ rounds, and at every location in the final $n$ rounds. Am I misreading the question?

Comment: @user58697 Every team plays for $2n$ rounds. That is just enough to play in each of the $n$ locations twice. There is no problem. Maybe you are assuming that every pair of players plays together exactly once, but this is never stated. Instead, each player plays every other player, and plays one other opponent twice.

Answer (score 1):

This is too long for a comment, but not an answer.

Obviously we can see that it works for two teams, and doesn't work for two teams. For two teams, if teams $A,B$ play at location $1$ in round $1$, then in order for them to play at each location in each of the first two rounds, $A$ and $B$ must both move to location $2$ at round $2$. So $A$ plays $B$ twice. By exactly the same reasoning, whomever $A$ plays in round $3$ will also be played by $A$ again in round $4$, so $A$ plays against at most two of the three other teams.

We can also see that it does not work for six teams. However, the method does not work for $n=4$. I did write some code to do check every single case for $n=4$, and I did not find any that worked. However, I'm a mathematician, not a programmer, so don't quote me on that. The case $n=5$ was already too large for my code to do a case by case check.

For $n=3$, let's suppose we have such a tournament schedule where every one of the six teams plays all five other teams, each team plays at each of the three locations in the first three rounds, and each team plays again at each of the three locations in the last three rounds. Let's make two graphs $G_F$, $G_S$. For each, the vertices will be the six teams. In the first graph $G_F$, make two edges adjacent if those two teams play each other in any of the first three rounds. In the second graph $G_S$, make two adjacent edges adjacent if those two teams play each other in any of the last three rounds. I claim that $G_F$ is a complete $3,3$ bipartite graph, using only the requirement that each team play at each location among the first three rounds. The exact same argument, using only the requirement that each team play at each location among the last three rounds, will show that $G_S$ is also a complete $3,3$ bipartite graph. But these two facts make it impossible for each team to play each of the five other teams. We'll get to that at the end.

Suppose two teams, call them $A,B$, meet at round $i\in \{1,2,3\}$ in location $j$. If they also meet in round $i'\in \{1,2,3\}\setminus \{i\}$, then since they can't repeat a location among the first three rounds, they'll meet in round $i'$ at some $j'\in \{1,2,3\}\setminus \{j\}$. Then in order to play at all three locations in the first three rounds, $A,B$ must also meet in round $i''\in \{1,2,3\}\setminus \{i,i'\}$ at the one location $j''\in \{1,2,3\}\setminus \{j,j'\}$ they haven't played at in the round $i,i'$. So if a pair of teams repeats once in the first three rounds, they actually must repeat twice, which is impossible. Because then these teams could face at most $3$ additional teams in rounds $4$ through $6$, and face at most $4<5$ teams overall. Therefore no pair of teams can meet twice within the first three rounds.

I also claim that if team $A$ plays two different teams $B,C$ among the first three rounds, then $B,C$ cannot play each other among the first three rounds. Suppose that the rounds are called $i,j,k$ (not necessarily assuming $i<j<k$) and suppose that the locations are $p,q,r$. Suppose that $A,B$ play in round $i$ at location $p$ and $A,C$ play in round $j$ at location $q$. The reason is because in round $k$, $B$ must be at location $q$, which is where $C$ is in round $j\neq k$. To see why, note that $B$ is at $p\neq q$ at $i$, and can't be at $q$ at $j$ because that's when/where $A$ is playing $C$. So $B$'s visit to $q$ must be at round $k$. And we know $C$ was at $q$ in round $j\neq k$.

Combining the two preceding paragraphs, we see that for a team $A$, $A$ must play three distinct teams (no repeats) in the first three rounds, and none of the teams $A$ plays can play each other among the first three rounds. This gives the complete bipartite $3,3$ graph claim. The argument for the last three rounds is the same.

Now fix any team $A$ and let $B,C$ be the two teams $A$ doesn't play in the first three rounds. In the last three rounds, the teams are split into two sets of three (call them $S,T$) such that the matches are all one team from $S$ and one from $T$. Without loss of generality, $A\in S$. If $B\in S$, then $A,B$ never play each other. If $B\in T$, then either $A,C$ never play (if $C\in S$) or $B,C$ never play (if $C\in T$).

Comment: Thx. When writing a program, remember to remove redundancy at the level of renumbering of teams and to remove redundancy in the ordering of the $n$ games, re-ordering the first $n$ rounds and re-ordering the final $n$ rounds. (Not that I have a detailed prescription on how to remove these redundancies)

Comment: I initially attempted to check for and remove redundancies of that type for the case of eight teams. The code ran faster by iterating through the whole list (including redundancies) and checking if they satisfied the requirements than it did to check whether a particular configuration was redundant. However, I was taking the quick route and using a lot of built in functions from the itertools package. There's almost certainly a better way to remove redundancies, but not one that fit well with methods  I picked for generating candidate configurations to start with.

Comment: I'm not sure we're on the same page: removing redundancies could start with fixing (in the case of 8 teams) the first 4 entries of the top row (I'm assuming a 4 row, 8 column table) to have the entries (1,2) , (3,4) , (5,6) , (7,8) and that team 1 plays along the diagonal in the leftmost 4 x 4 array and along the diagonal of the rightmost 4 x 4 array. Such a simplification can be achieved using relabeling of teams, games and rounds. The point is just that not all "gauge-freedom" has been exploited with these fixations and I don't know of a prescription which does exhaust all gauge-freedom.

Comment: Right. How many configurations does this leave?

Comment: Sorry if I have offended or misunderstood you. If your question is what gauge-freedom remains after the initial configuration described in the previous comment: I think one can get that initial configuration using only team and column relabeling and row relabeling hasn't been used fundamentally (but careful, because if you start using row relabeling you perturb the diagonal and you'll have to employ column relabeling to restore the diagonal, but by using column relabeling you have perturbed the top row... so it's not that simple)

Comment: I'm not offended. I agree with your assessment of those reductions. My point is that the problem is still very large. The programmatically lazy way is to use the itertools.permutations and itertools.combinations packages. Each round can be thought of as a permutation on $\{1,\ldots, 8\}$, where the permutation $(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)$ means $1,2$ play at location $1$, $3,4$ play at $2$, etc. If we only have ways to get all permutations and combinations, we have $8!$ choose $8$ ways to pick the rounds.

Comment: Your reductions would take that down to $7!$ choose $7$.

Comment: Of course, this is a ridiculous overcounting. But for my approach, it was faster to go through a big list which had some configurations represented multiple times than it was to go through that list and remove things which were redundant.

Comment: I see where you're coming from. Without having to quit laziness, note that the problem doesn't require ordered pairs in the table entries, which should reduce the complexity by a large power of 2.

Comment: There is a built in function for getting all permutations. There's not a built in function for looking at all of the ways to partition an $8$ element set into an ordered list of four unordered pairs. And this is what I was trying to say before: Checking whether permutations correspond to the same configuration of game is so computationally expensive, that it's faster just to look at all permutations (including redundancies) than it is to try to filter out the redundancies and only check whether any of those satisfy the requirements.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151752/discussion-between-5th-decile-and-user469053).

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $n\geq 7$ and $n$ odd, then such a tournament schedule exists.

For the first $n$ rounds, we arrange for game $k\in\{1,...,n\}$ to played at round $j\in\{1,...,n\}$ by the following pair of teams: team $(k-j) \text{ mod } n$ plays against team $((k+j) \text{ mod }n)+n$. (I use here a mod function that maps to $\{1,...,n\}$)

In this way, each of the teams $1,...,n$ will have played against each of the teams $n+1,...,2n$ in the first $n$ rounds.

For the final $n$ rounds, the schedule will rely on an [auxiliary standardized skew room square](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/journal-of-the-australian-mathematical-society/article/spectrum-of-skew-room-squares/90AA1CB747C6E3B80E4819B6ECB4BDB4) $S_n$ of size $n \times n$ and using the standard alphabet $\{\infty,1,...,n\}$. Such a [Room square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Room_square) has the pair $(\infty,x)$ in its $(x,x)-$entry (i.e. the $x$'th entry along the diagonal) and if the $(i,j)-$entry is non-empty, then the $(j,i)-$entry is empty.

Remove the $\infty$ symbols from the diagonal entries in $S_n$ (the resulting object $S_n'$ has unpaired numbers in the diagonal). Now let $Q_n$ be the $n\times n$ square obtained by transposing $S_n'$ and adding $n$ to all of the numbers in all of the entries (The entries of $Q_n$ contain numbers ranging from $n+1$ to $2n$). Superimpose $S_n'$ and $Q_n$ (meaning, assign to the entry $(i,j)$ the union of the content in $(S_n')_{ij}$ and the content in $(Q_n)_{ij}$) to get a $n\times n$ square $D_n$, which gives a suitable schedule for the final $n$ rounds. (It doesn't matter whether you interpret the rows or the columns as resp. the game type vs. game round)